# Why does Perl module Crypt::SSLeay give an error upon loading?

Tags: perl, module, openssl, perl-module

I am trying to get WWW::Mechanize to login to Yahoo using https; however, it requires the use of Crypt::SSLeay for sending over https.

Crypt::SSLeay installed succesfully, and openssl was already installed on the system.

However, it gives the error upon loading:

---

`Can't load '/home/gen19/perl5/lib/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/i686-linux//auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so' for module Crypt::SSLeay: /home/gen19/perl5/lib/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/i686-linux//auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: undefined symbol: PL_sv_undef at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.0/i386-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 229.
 at /home/gen19/lwp4 line 15
Compilation failed in require at /home/gen19/lwp4 line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/gen19/lwp4 line 15.`

---

The installation of Crypt::SSLeay was successful, and could recognize the installation of openssl (here):

```
perl Makefile.PL
=======================================================
Only one OpenSSL installation found at /usr
Consider running 'perl Makefile.PL --default' the next
time Crypt::SSLeay is upgraded to select this directory
automatically thereby avoiding the following prompt.
=======================================================
Which SSL install path do you want to use? [/usr] /home/gen19/ssldir

BUILD INFORMATION
================================================
ssl library: OpenSSL 0.9.8 in /home/gen19/ssldir
ssl header:  openssl/ssl.h
libraries:   -L/home/gen19/ssldir/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lgcc
include dir: -I/home/gen19/ssldir/include/openssl -I/usr/kerberos/include
================================================
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lgcc
Writing Makefile for Crypt::SSLeay
The test suite can attempt to connect to public servers
to ensure that the code is working properly. If you are
behind a strict firewall or have no network connectivity,
these tests may fail (through no fault of the code).

Do you want to run the live tests (y/N) ? [N]
```

---

NOTE: recently installed Perl v5.10.1 using App::perlbrew, due to LWP::UserAgent's needing it. I installed Crypt::SSLeay using my new version of Perl.

I don't have root priveldiges, as I am doing this on a remote server at school. Please tell me why it's giving the error even though it installed succesfully. I know it has something to do with the shared libraries, but the installation recognized them.

SIDE NOTE: my script works fine if I don't say "use Crypt::SSLeay;" at the start, but it gives the error when I use https that it's not a supported protocol, and needs LWP::protocol::https installed. Installing that always fails.

EDIT: Thanks for your help, CJM. Apparently it was using the old version of Perl when I executed, but now I've fixed that.

It doesn't give that error anymore; however, it still says

```
Error GETing https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym: Protocol scheme     'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed) at lwp4 line 14
```

I thought Crypt::SSLeay was supposed to take care of this.

Comment: Nope, you need to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https). Now, [Crypt::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay) specifies `LWP::Protocol::https` as a dependency, so I don't know why it did not get installed. Also, [you probably don't need `Crypt::SSLeay`](https://www.nu42.com/2014/08/dont-declare-dependency-on-cryptssleay.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you examine the error message, you'll notice it mentions both 5.10.1 and 5.8.0 (in the Perl library paths).  This indicates that you're trying to use a module built for one version of Perl with a different version.  XS-based Perl modules (i.e. ones that include C code) are not binary compatible between major releases of Perl.

It appears you installed Crypt::SSLeay using Perl 5.10.1, and are trying to use it with 5.8.0.  That won't work.  Use only Perl 5.10.x with that installation.  If you need to use it with Perl 5.8.0 also, install another copy in a different directory.

Comment: Thanks, apparently it was executing the script using the old version of Perl. However, it still gives does not let me connect through https, saying "Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed)". Any hunch on Why? I thought Crypt::SSLeay was responsible for it.

Comment: @Johnny, if you're using LWP version 6, then LWP::Protocol::https has to be installed separately.